# Reduce voltage from transformer

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, transformer, bridge-rectifier

[image: image of my circuit]

I am trying to build a variable power supply using a transformer with a 12V 0 12V - 5 ampere output. I am using a BR1010 rectifier. I have connected the 2 - 12V wires from the transformer to the AC input of rectifier. At the output of the rectifier I have connected 2 - 25V 2200uF capacitors in series. The output I am getting through the capacitor is 40V. How is this voltage increasing?

I want to pass this into a XL4015 step down module so that I can control the voltage in a more proper manner but the input range for this module seems to be maximum 36V.

What can be done in this case? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated. I am posting few pics of my circuit.

Yellow wire is 12V-12V output from the  transformer that is connected to input of the BR1010. The red and black wires are connected to the capacitor in series (2*25V). PS: Ignore the red wire to the XL4015 module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I am trying to build a variable power supply using a transformer 12 0
> 12*

The other option is to use this type of configuration: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electric-shocks.com/center-tapped-full-wave-rectifier-with-capacitor-filter/).

Notice that the centre-tap is 0 volts and the peak voltage on the DC output is 12 volts x \$\sqrt2\$ = 17 volts. With a 0.7 volt drop in the diodes, you should get 16 volts no problem. If you needed a negative supply you can double up on the rectifiers and reservoir capacitor and liberate the same DC supply (in addition to the positive supply) but one that is negative negative. On your current setup you can measure from the centre-tap to either side of the bridge rectifier output and see this for yourself: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www.interfacebus.com/Glossary-of-Terms-full-wave-bridge-rectifier-circuit.html).

But the question remains; is this now too low for your XL4015 module and what you are trying to achieve? You haven't stated the minimum expected level you require so only you can answer this. The XL4015 will work down to about 8 volts I believe.

> *The output I am getting through capacitor is 40v. How is this voltage
> increasing*

Your AC secondary output is 24 volts and, when rectified and smoothed, you will get a DC voltage of 24 volts x \$\sqrt2\$ = 34 volts but, this can be a lot higher on an unloaded transformer hence you see 40 volts DC.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for such a quick and detailed response. I will be using this variable power supply for various purpose such as using my wired trimmer that needs 3 volts or powering my 775 motor that will accept anywhere between 12-24 volt. I am trying to achieve this voltage regulation using xl4015 module. But as I mentioned using a full bridge rectifier gives me 40v, which is higher than the max input for the module.

Comment: I tried using half wave rectifier configuration using the 0 tap on transformer and 12v tap but output is of 20 v max. And that is too low for me. A ideal setup for me would be to be able to feed around 30-35 volt into xl4015 module. Now I am planning to use a resistor of 39/47kilo ohm to reduce the original output voltage of 40v to 35 volt. Will that be any good I doubt.

Comment: @yoyo What current will you be taking on full load and, how much does the 40 volts drop when you are taking two thirds to three quarters of full load current? 39 to 47 kohm will likely be far too big. You need to use a different method but that can't be determined until you report back with the values I asked for.

Comment: Hi Andy. The max current of the module is rated 5amp, also the transformer is of 5amp. Also the nature of work I'll be doing using 775 motor can require 5 amp. So max current of 5 amp would be perfect in my scenario. Regarding resistor, I plan to have my connection with combination of 10k ohm and 39/47k ohm. I used the formula to get this value. See example for formula http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-reduce-voltage-with-resistors.php

Comment: 5 amps through 10 kohm dissipates a power of 0.25 mega watt. Think again.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see v=ir working here... So is there some buck converter that I can construct or purchase off store that is able to handle 42 volt input and allow me to regulate voltage like xl4015 without current loss or extreme heat generation. The ones available commercially typically claim to support max 40v.

Comment: Yes there are many from the normal sources such as TI, Analog devices etc... But you might as well go the whole hog and get rid of the XL module and replace with a variable buck converter.

Comment: Is there any buck converter that you would suggest. I tried searching online but nothing concrete came up

Comment: Hi Andy, I do have a idea though. Can I do some cheating and get it to work in this way:I will use the setup in half wave rectifier mode. That gives me around 20 volts at no load. If I use a boost converter https://www.electronicscomp.com/150w-dc-dc-step-up-boost-converter-10-32v-to-12-35v-adjustable-power-supply-module-india and set its output to say 32 volt and then pass this to the buck converter xl4015 which will allow me to control voltage from 1-32 v. Will this setup be able to provide max current of 5 amps at full load

Comment: You can either start high and regulate down with a buck or start low and regulate up using a boost.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and replies Andy, But the question of whether it there will be current loss still exists. Can you please provide some input on that. Thanks again for all your help 

Comment: There will only be power loss to consider. Your output power to input power will be about 85%.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer is rated at 12-0-12 VAC at 5A, so the open circuit voltage without a load is higher than that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Since I'm using both 12 v taps from transformer as input to rectifier I think it's generating 40v after rectification. But how can I reduce that 40 v to match the input for my xl4015 module (it's rated max 36v). Will a simple resistor do the job?